# Showing that $F_1(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty} f(x+n)$ is continuous for $f$ a Schwartz function on the real line

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity

> Given a Schwartz function $f\in S(\mathbb{R})$ on the real line, we can construct a new function on the circle by the recipe
>
> $$F_1 (x)=\sum ^{\infty}_{n=-\infty} f(x+n)$$
>
> Since $f$ is rapidly decreasing, the series converges absolutely and uniformly on every compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, so $F_1$ is continuous.

Could someone please explain what theorem are we using here? How do we rigorously show that $F_1$ is absolutely and uniformly convergent? (I think intuitively it is very true, especially given that $F_1$ is periodic, but I have trouble proving it)

Comment: Who says $f$ is rapidly decreasing? How rapidly, exactly?

Comment: @vonbrand This is from Stein & Shakarchi. In this book, rapidly decreasing is equivalent to being Schwarz function.

Comment: "...a new function on the circle..." What circle?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I think by circle it means $F_1$ is periodic with period 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists $C \in (0,\infty)$ such that $|x^{2}f(x)| \leq C$. For $0\leq x\leq T$ this gives $|f(x+n) | \leq \frac  C {(x+n)^{2}} \leq \frac C {n^{2}}$. Apply M-test to see that the series converges uniformly on $[0,T]$ for any $T>0$. I will leave $x<0$ to you.

Comment: Thank you so much. And how are we showing that the series, which is a function defined on real number, is continuous? I know there is a similar theorem for the function defined in the complex domain (i.e. if $f_n$ is continuous and uniformly convergent in every compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$ then $f$ is continuous). Do I need to go back to the proof of that theorem and adopt it to the case when the domain is real?

Comment: I don't know why you think that the theorem you are referring to is valid only in the complex case It is proved first for real case and the complex case comes later. Any book on Calculus proves that the sum of a unifomly convergent series of continuous functions is continuous.  @jk001